# Função de Login

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde

Tive um problema com meu script de login, ele informa que o e-mail não existe no banco, o problema que eu sempre fiz desse jeito, e agora não faço a menor ideia do que fiz de errado

Função de login

```
function login($conexao, $email, $senha)
    {
        // Requerindo arquivos
        require_once "ControleAcesso.php";

        // Objeto controle de acesso
        $controleAcesso = new ControleAcesso();

        // query que varre o banco atras do e-mail informado
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";

        // Executa a query
        $busca = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

        // Valida a existencia do email
        if($busca->num_rows)
        {
            // Obtendo linha de resultado
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca);

            // Obtendo senha armazenada no banco me formato hash
            $hash = $row['senha'];

            // Valida senha
            if(password_verify($senha, $hash))
            {
                // Informa que o usuario foi lagado com sucesso
                $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuario logado com sucesso!";

                // Atribuido senha na nova sessao do usuario
                $controleAcesso->loginUsuario($row['email']);

                // TODO Redirecionando para a pagina interna do sistema
                header("Location: ../Index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                // Informa que o email e/ou a senha estao incorretos
                $_SESSION["danger"] = "senha incorretos";

                // Redireciona para a pagina de index
                header("Location: ../Index.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($busca);

            // Informa que o email e/ou a senha estao incorretos
            $_SESSION["danger"] = "E-mail incorretos";

            // Redireciona para a pagina de index
            header("Location: ../Index.php");
        }

        // Encerra execucao
        die();
    }
```

Var_dump me retorna

```
object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: Bom consegui resolver o problema, o nome do campo estava incorreto, o script acima esta correto